# $_SESSION doesn't seem to work across files?

Tags: php, html, css, session

I am making a game for my computing class. The user has to change settings of their robot before playing. Most are using Visual Basic or Game Maker but I felt more comfortable with web based languages.

The issue I have just run into is when I am checking whether $_SESSION variables are set. This is a screenshot of my script:

http://i60.tinypic.com/2ia4hnr.jpg

As you can see on the left their is a button called "Play". On the customisation page the user fills in all the settings and they are stored as $_SESSION variables however when I use the `If` statement on all other pages it always sees them as not being set, so it does not allow them to play.

This is the `customise.php` page code (sorry for posting all the code but I felt it was needed for me to best explain my issue):

```
<?php $layout_context = "public"; ?>
<?php include("header.php"); ?>

<div id="main">
  <div id="navigation">
    <h2><i><u>Navigation</u></i></h2>
<br />
<u><a href="index.php">Welcome</a><br /><br />
<u><a href="instructions.php">How to Play?</a></u><br /><br />
<u><a href="customise.php"><font color="orange">Customisation</font></a></u><br /><br />
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['RobotName'], $_SESSION['traction'], $_SESSION['passenger'])) {
?>
<u><a href="game.php">Play</a></u>
<?php 
  } else {
  ?>
  <u><a href="#" onclick="alert('You must customise your robot first before playing!');">Play</a></u>
  <?php 
}
?>
  </div>
 <div id="page">
        <h1>Robot Customisation</h1>
        <br />
        <p><h3>Welcome to the BotMod Robot Customisation!</h3><br />
            Below you will have three options that enable you to play BotMod. Those are: Your Robot name, Traction Type and Passenger Size.<br /> See the bottom of this page for further guidance.<br /><br />
<br />
<form id="settings" name="settings" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <h4>Robot Name:</h4> <input type="text" name="RobotName"><br />
    <h4>Traction Type:</h4>
    <select  name="traction">
        <option value="">Please Select Your Traction Type...</option>
  <option value="Wheels">Wheels</option>
  <option value="Tracks">Tracks</option>
  <option value="Skis">Skis</option>
</select>
<br />
<h4>Passenger Size:</h4>
    <select  name="passenger">
        <option value="">Please Select Your Passenger Size...</option>
  <option value="Large">Large</option>
  <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
  <option value="Small">Small</option>
</select>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save Settings" />
</form>
<?php 
require_once("session_start.php");
// Store all submitted $_POST fields to their own $_SESSION ID to be called
// later. Must use session_start();
if (isset($_POST['Submit']) && $_POST['RobotName'] != '' && $_POST['traction'] != '' && $_POST['passenger'] != '') {
    $_SESSION['RobotName'] = $_POST['RobotName'];
    $_SESSION['traction'] = $_POST['traction'];
    $_SESSION['passenger'] = $_POST['passenger'];
} elseif (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<strong>Error: You must complete all fields on this page!</strong><br />";
}

?>
<br />
<style> 
div.container
{
width:30em;
border:1em solid;
}
div.box
{
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
width: 50%;
border: 1em solid red;
float: left;
}
</style>
<?php if (isset($_POST['Submit']) && $_POST['RobotName'] != '' && $_POST['traction'] != '' && $_POST['passenger'] != '') {
echo "<h4>Your Settings (Click Play BotMod) to begin.</h4>";
?>
<div class="container">
<div class="box"><strong><i>Robot Name:</i></strong> <?php echo $_SESSION['RobotName']; ?><br /></div>
<div class="box"><strong><i>Traction:</i></strong> <?php echo $_SESSION['traction']; ?><br /></div>
<div class="box"><strong><i>Passenger:</i></strong> <?php echo $_SESSION['passenger']; ?><br /></div>
<div class="box"><strong><a href="game.php">Play BotMod</a></strong><br /></div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
<?php 
}
?>
  </div>
</div>

<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

As you can see I have created an `If` statement on the play navigation.

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['RobotName'], $_SESSION['traction'], $_SESSION['passenger'])) {
?>
<u><a href="game.php">Play</a></u>
<?php 
  } else {
  ?>
  <u><a href="#" onclick="alert('You must customise your robot first before playing!');">Play</a></u>
  <?php 
}
?>
```

This doesn't work on any of the pages: `customise.php` `index.php` or `instructions.php`.
I have created the variables on the `customise.php` page with this code:

```
If (isset($_POST['Submit']) && $_POST['RobotName'] != '' && $_POST['traction'] != '' && $_POST['passenger'] != '') {
    $_SESSION['RobotName'] = $_POST['RobotName'];
    $_SESSION['traction'] = $_POST['traction'];
    $_SESSION['passenger'] = $_POST['passenger'];
} elseif (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<strong>Error: You must complete all fields on this page!</strong><br />";
}

?>
```

My index.php navigation code:

```
    <u><a href="index.php"><font color="orange">Welcome</font></a><br /><br />
    <u><a href="instructions.php">How to Play?</a></u><br /><br />
    <u><a href="customise.php">Customisation</a></u><br /><br />
    <?php require_once("session_start.php"); ?>
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['RobotName'], $_SESSION['traction'], $_SESSION['passenger'])) {
    ?>
    <u><a href="game.php">Play</a></u>
    <?php 
      } else {
      ?>
<u><a href="#" onclick="alert('You must customise your robot first before playing!');">Play</a></u>
  <?php 
}
?>
```

So does anyone know why the `$_SESSION` variables do not seem to work? I am using MAMP for this at the moment just in case that has something to do with it.

Comment: Do you use `session_start()` on every page

Comment: Yes I have required the file `session_start.php` in all of the files which contains this code: `<?php session_start(); ?>`.

Comment: @MattKent It can't be `session start.php` it can be `session-start.php` or `session_start.php` ;) Just try and put `<?php session_start() ?>` on the first line of your document which use session variables

Comment: I didn't use it at the top of the page. Found my issue thank you everyone :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`session_start();` must be called at the top of every page where you use the `$_SESSION` variable.

Documentation: http://php.net/function.session-start

Comment: That was my issue. I didn't define it at the top of the page. :)

Answer (score 2):

use session start method

example :

```
session_start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call session_start() before accessing any session variables